# Enviar variables jquery a php

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando actualizar un valor en bbdd una vez hago click a un botón.
Los botones contienen dos tipos de texto: "Active" o "Inactive" y lo que trato de hacer es que al seleccionar Active, este pase a Inactive.
Para ello, tengo un php que me debería de hacer la actualización:

```
<?php
include("db_connection.php");
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $register_status = $_POST['register_status'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = '$register_status'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

a nivel de Jquery tengo lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(id){
  $('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
  var button = jQuery(e.target);
        if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
          button.data('status', 'Inactive');
          button.html('Inactive');

       $.post("ajax/updateStatus.php", {
                id: id,
                register_status: "Inactive"
            },
            function (data, status) {
                readRecords();
            }
        );
        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
          button.data('status', 'Active');
          button.html('Active');
        }
  });
})
```

como ejemplo, estoy seguiendo otra función que tengo donde le paso únicamente el id y si me elimina la fila en la bbdd.

```
function DeleteUser(id) {
        $.post("ajax/deleteUser.php", {
                id: id
            },
            function (data, status) {
                readRecords();
            }
        );
}
```

***deleteUser.php***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['id']) != "")
{
    include("db_connection.php");
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
?>
```

y al hacer click, lo elimino:

```
<li onclick="DeleteUser('.$row['id'].')"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
```

Que sucede para que no realice la actualización?

Comment: Hola nuevamente @Guif If, ¿por favor podrias detallar la pregunta para poder ayudarte?.

Comment: buenas! claro. Tengo un botón con el texto "Active" que al hacer click se cambia a "Inactive". Ahora estoy intentando que este texto también se guarde en la BBDD por lo que intento enviar los datos mediate post. Como ejemplo, he cogido otra función (DeleteUser) la cual me funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar con lo siguiente, cambie el orden del **$.post** y la linea **register_status: button.html()**.

```js
$(document).ready(function(id){
  $('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
  var button = jQuery(e.target);
        if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
          button.data('status', 'Inactive');
          button.html('Inactive');
        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
          button.data('status', 'Active');
          button.html('Active');
        }

       $.post("ajax/updateStatus.php", {
                id: id,
                register_status: button.html()
            },
            function (data, status) {
                readRecords();
            }
        );

  });
})
```

A la espera de tu respuesta.

Comment: ok. con esto ahora siempre se ejecutará y cogerá la variable button.html() que venga del if, pero no veo que me envie los valores al php para hacer el update

Comment: En el ejemplo **function DeleteUser(id)**, ¿puedes mostrar como es el boton que realiza esa acción?, el html por favor

Comment: Disculpa por tardar. He actualizado con el codigo que me ejecutaria ***DeleteUser***